# How to make an image responsive from CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding an image in my css class. Now I need to use the `img-responsive` Bootstrap method to make this image responsive. How can I do this ?

My code:

CSS

```
.mybackground {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  vertical-align: top;
    background: url(img.png) ;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}
```

Note: I have added the image in the CSS class.

Comment: If is a background image on a element you don't need to make the background responsive, you should do the element responsive.

Comment: This is applied on a DIV. And How do I make it responsive.

Comment: Use `@media` tags.

Comment: I also seem to have a similar problem. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Does the image maintain a consistent aspect ratio?

Comment: what do you mean by consistent aspect ratio ? Sorry I am a newbie

Comment: The problem is that using the image as a background image takes it out of the document flow.  Normally an image will maintain its own height as you set it to be 100% width of its container.  This keeps the image responsive.  When you use it as a background image that's lost. You can "fake" it, but only if the images you are using have a consistent aspect ratio.  Aspect ratio is the width relative to the height. For example, a 400x300 image has the same aspect ratio as a 800x600 image.  Those would be 4:3 aspect ratio.  If all images you use with `.mybackground` are similar it's easier.

Comment: If this applies to only one image and you're certain the image won't change much,it'll be easier.  You could do something like `.mybackground {width: 100%; height: 0; padding-top: 75%} `.  It's called the "padding trick". By setting a percentage top padding (which is relative to the parent's width), you can simulate image responsiveness when using an element with a background image.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend taking a look at the following:

First the `img` items in Bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Then confirm you have the appropriate media calls taking place:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your `CSS`.

```
 height: 100%;
 background: url(".....") no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% auto;
```

Comment: What's with the odd, relative path to `../images/header.png`? O_o

Comment: don't mind it. It was an example. haha @JosephMarikle